# How to change the location of a groupbox programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello guys i Need to know how to Change the Location of the groupbox with code.
The Groupbox is in a Canvas.

Comment: Change the location property of GroupBox.

Comment: I Need it on code .left does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Canvas has two attached properties - left and top.

You can do:

```
    MyGroupBox.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,50.0);
```

And similarly with topproperty where mygroupbox is your groupbox.
50 is a double and the distance in px from top or left edge of the canvas the top left corner of the goupbox is to be located.

Comment: What code should i Show if there is nothing to Show ?????

Comment: @check2410 `What code should i Show if there is nothing to Show` tells us there was no attempt and or research at solving the issue. Name calling doesn't do any justice here, remember you came here with an issue asking *us* for help... Also there is a reason why as to the downvote, when and *if* the question is closed it will explain why...

Comment: I think the downvoting is little harsh. There's not too much to this but only when you know what to do.  Once you know what the answer is then yes it's fairly easy to find a sample. If you don't have a clue and you're new to wpf then it's perhaps not so obvious attached properties even exist. You're likely to be looking for some property on the groupbox.  What's he really supposed to show us? A groupbox in a canvas and a statement he doesn't know what to do?

Comment: Yea just what Andy said. What should i Show ? I am not being lazy but i can not Show you anything that i don't have. I could write i tried MyComboBox.left = 50 for example but i obviously did not because that is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(this.groupBox, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(this.groupBox, 100);
```

You can use Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop static methods if you want to set location of an element which is in a canvas.

[image]

Button A Click

```
Canvas.SetLeft(this.groupBox, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(this.groupBox, 100);
```

Button B Click (0,0 means Top Left Corner)

```
Canvas.SetLeft(this.groupBox, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(this.groupBox, 0);
```